# Stop the fs2-stream after a timeout

Tags: scala, fs2

I want to use a function similar to `take(n: Int)` but in a time dimension:
`consume(period: Duration`. So I want a stream to terminate if a timeout occurs. I know that I could compile a stream to something like `IO[List[T]]` and cancel it, but then I'll lose the result. In reality I want to convert an endless stream into a limited one and preserve the results.

More on the wider scope of the problem. I have an endless stream of events from a messaging broker, but I also have rotating credentials to connect to the broker. So what I want is to consume the stream of events for some time, then stop, acquire new credentials, connect again to the broker creating a new stream and concatenate two streams into one.

Answer (score 7):

There is a method, that does exactly this:

```
/**
    * Interrupts this stream after the specified duration has passed.
    */
  def interruptAfter[F2[x] >: F[x]: Concurrent: Timer](duration: FiniteDuration): Stream[F2, O]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like that

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import fs2._
import fs2.concurrent.SignallingRef
implicit val ex = ExecutionContext.global
implicit val t: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ex)
implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ex)

val effect: IO[Long] = IO.sleep(1.second).flatMap(_ => IO{
  val next = Random.nextLong()
  println("NEXT: " + next)
  next
})
val signal = SignallingRef[IO, Boolean](false).unsafeRunSync()
val timer = Stream.sleep(10.seconds).flatMap(_ => 
  Stream.eval(signal.set(true)).flatMap(_ => 
    Stream.emit(println("Finish")).covary[IO]))

val stream = timer concurrently 
Stream.repeatEval(effect).interruptWhen(signal)

stream.compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
```

Also if you want to save your result of publishing data you need to have some unbounded Queue from fs2 for converting published data to your result via queue.stream